# Using a RDBMS in an offline Chrome app

Tags: sql, postgresql, indexeddb, google-chrome-app

I need to develop an app which has the following requirements:

- Being a [Chrome app](http://developer.chrome.com/apps/about_apps.html) that works offline
- Data retrieval is fast, flexible and support large objects (there are 100,000 500KB text strings). I don't know much about noSQL databases, but it seems to me a traditional RDBMS would fit our dataset better (list of 300+ questions among 30000+ respondents, list of 1000+ objects with 1 and 0s on 100+ variables, etc.).

I am having problems finding suitable technologies. Among my solutions:

- Using a client/server model with a PostgreSQL database, with the client caching queries. *Problem*: less efficient (requires network transactions) and can only use previous queries offline.
- Using IndexedDB (WebSQL is deprecated so this is not an option). *Problem*: I think a RDBMS would fit our dataset better. Plus I am not sure if IndexedDB will handle the multitude of large 500KB text strings.

The best would be to let the client download the PostgreSQL database and run the SQL queries locally, but I don't think it's possible. What would you do?

Comment: Are you really expecting your users to download 500GB of data when they want to work offline? I think you'll have to look into caching results.

Comment: It's actually 50GB but you are actually raising a very good point here :)

Answer (score 1):

For Chrome App, you can do. As long as user have enough space, 500 GB is not a problem. It does not have SQL, but index base key range query will do most of your query job.

Definitely check out [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20362184/is-it-possible-to-write-objects-to-a-file-during-an-indexeddb-transaction) for dumping your data to IndexedDB without crashing due to out of memory. Basically transfer data in chunk and write to IndexedDB.

Comment: Thanks a lot. So the data size can be handled (although asking for 50GB of user space is a bit crazy as Richard H. pointed out). However I would rather use an SQL database since that's what we use for statistical analysis in the backend (that would mean having the same data in two different formats)