# Is it possible to write objects to a file during an IndexedDb transaction?

Tags: javascript, indexeddb, filewriter

I have an objectStore with hundreds of objects in it that I can view with code like this:

```
db // already set by call to window.indexedDB.open
.transaction(["mailing-list"])
.objectStore("mailing-list")
.openCursor()
.onsuccess = function (event) {
    var cursor = event.target.result;
    if (cursor) {
        console.log(cursor.value);
        cursor.continue();
    }
};
```

What I want to do is use a FileWriter to write out each object as it's retrieved; I don't want to accumulate all the objects in a giant array and write them all out at once. Nor do I want to start a separate transaction for each object, as I want to use a cursor to iterate through all the objects. (Without caring about their keys.)

I would put the call to fileWriter.write where the call to console.log is now. The call to cursor.continue() would be in the onwrite callback. Otherwise, I would be issuing a write before the previous one had completed, which is illegal.

This seems to be impossible, because, as writing is asynchronous, the "onsuccess" callback would return after write is called, thus ending the transaction and rendering the cursor invalid, even if it's captured in a closure.

Am I right about this? I'm about to code it to accumulate the entire collection of objects in memory, so I can write them after the cursor completes, although that's not my first choice.

(NOTE: I don't think there's a synchronous form of writing, but, even if there were, I couldn't use it as this code will be in a Chrome App.)

Comment: you can send the cursor.value to the writer, it won't vanish with the transaction.

Comment: Yes, that's fine for the first object. But, when that write completes, the transaction has completed (when its onsuccess function returns), so the cursor can't be advanced to the second object.

Comment: there's no reason to wait on a file to write out. just feed the writer the value and go next(). you can open a million file handles and pass the value to the writer during your transaction. why wait on a write to write? they stack up fine. you can go to the next one before the writer is done. in other words, you potentially write to all of the files at once. it's all async, so it just works. if it's not dead-simple reconsider your approach.

Comment: I don't think that's correct. According to the spec for FileWriter.write (http://www.w3.org/TR/file-writer-api/#idl-def-FileWriter):

"If readyState is WRITING, throw an InvalidStateError and terminate this series of steps."

(I'm not sure what you mean by "file handles". I should maybe emphasize that I'm using the W3C File API, and not a generic file API.)

Comment: i really think you are over-thinking this. simply make a new saver function that you pass a filename and a value, and replace your console.log call with a call to that function. the saver function should make a new FileWriter and set it with the value and filename passed, how long it takes to finish or what happens to the cursor while it's writing doesn't matter; that value has already been passed to the saver function. in short, if console.log can do it, so can a saver function.

Comment: No, I think you're missing something. The problem isn't with FileWriter per se. The problem is that the onsuccess function for the transaction must not be allowed to return without another request pending, or else the transaction is terminated. Yet, the request for the next cursor position cannot be issued until the write completes, or else multiple writes will be stacked up. Each write must be allowed to complete before the next write is issued.

Comment: what's so bad about stacking up writes? seems better than loading everything to ram at once...

Comment: Probably nothing, and, indeed, that was my first attempt. However, it is illegal and results in an error, as it's not allowed to issue a write when a write is still in the WRITING state.

Comment: the only reason that error would happen is if you were recycling FileWriter instances, or trying to use just one to save more than one file. "new FileWriter" needs to appear in you code once for each file.

Comment: Only one file, Dan. The entire database dump is to be in a single file, as this is for database backup. It's required that such a feature be in the app, because IndexedDB databases cannot be shared between apps. It's the FileWriter.write calls that can't overlap, one per object.

Comment: that changes everything until an append() method is released. capture to RAM, dump to disk.

Answer (score 0):

You can do as long as you has enough buffer between the two async processors.

I have blog a bit how this is done [here](http://dev.yathit.com/ydn-db/transaction.html):

Consider for populating a store with records from a large delimited text. To avoid holding memory for holding all records, data are download by chunk using HTTP Range header by CsvStreamer and invoke next callback when it read a record. A chunk of data comprise multiple records and in that case CsvStreamer write synchronously. While waiting for next chunk of data CsvStreamer invoke next callback asynchronously.

```
var db = new ydn.db.Storage(db_name, schema, options);
var stream = new CsvStreamer(url);
var isSerial = false;
var tdb = db.thread('multi', isSerial); // multi-request parallel transactions
var putData = function(data) {
  if (data) { 
    tdb.put('store1', data).then(function() {
      stream.next(function (data) {   
        putData(data);
    }), function(e) {
      throw e;
    });     
  }
});

stream.next(function (data) {
  putData(data);
}
```

The trick is reuse the transaction if it is still active. Otherwise create a new transaction.

EDIT:

Yeah, above example is writing to idb, whereas you want reading. When piping async processors, you need to concern about the slowest one, that is FileWriter. Here is example:

```
var dump = function(marker) {
  var q = marker ? db.from('store name', '>', marker) : db.from('store name');
  q.open(function(cur) {
    var cb = writeToFile(cur.getValue());
    if (cb) { // wait me callback
       var next_key = cur.getKey();
       cb(function() {
         dump(next_key); // notice de-referencing cur, though not necessary
       });
       cb = null; // also not necessary, but better be on safe side of memory leak
       return null; // stop continuing cursor
    } else { // file writer said, good to call me again
      return undefined; // continue cursor
    }
  }, iter, 'readonly');
}

dump();
```

> Is it possible to write objects to a file during an IndexedDb transaction?

Short answer: No.

Comment: Your library is interesting, and I'm going to look into it. However, from the article you reference and from your example, I can't readily see how it applies to iterating over a database and writing the objects retrieved to a text file. (It's an "external" file, on the OS's file system; the operation I have in mind is an export feature.) If I'm not going to use a cursor, then breaking it up into multiple transactions is feasible. But I still don't see how to use a cursor to iterate over the objects, which was in my original statement of the problem I'm trying to solve.

Comment: In reading about your YDN-DB library, I see nothing about licensing. What kind of license is it?

Comment: Have you tested YDN-DB in Chrome Apps, or do you know whether it works with the restrictions enforced for Chrome Apps?

Comment: Yes, I use in chrome app and extension.  License can be found on every source code and minified file. It is Apache v2.

Comment: Yeah, above example is writing to idb, whereas you want reading. I have updated my answer.